# Constructor not returning usable object

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I have a problem with the constructor, which is not working as I'd expect.

If I try to initialize my class like that, it will work and I get a usable object:

```
vector<float> v;
MyClass<2> a(v);
```

However, if I try to build a class like below (which should be equivalent) the results are quite unexpected. There is no error message/warning when compiling or running the program. But if you try to use this variable a somewhere and call its methods (for example a.doSomething()), it will crash.

I put some code inside the constructor to notify me if it is used. It turned out that no code inside the constructor was actually executed in this case.

```
MyClass<2> a(vector<float>());
```

So I am wondering why this is happening? Is the 2nd declaration illegal?

EDIT: I will post some code of the class

```
template <int x>
class MyClass {
public:
    vector<float> v;
    MyClass<x>(vector<float> v1) {
      v = v1;
    }

};
```

Comment: The class has a public variable of the same type. So it will just assign the argument to the variable.

Comment: I posted some code of the class. It is not a reference or a pointer, just a variable.

Comment: don't understand why myclass<2>

Comment: Post the code that uses the vector (and causes the error)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
MyClass<2> a(vector<float>());
```

This is not a variable declaration.  It is the declaration of a function named `a` that returns a `MyClass<2>` object and takes as an argument a "pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns a `vector<float>`."  Confusing?  Yes.  This is what is referred to as the "most vexing parse."

You need extra parentheses:

```
MyClass<2> a((vector<float>()));
             ^               ^
```

Or, you can use copy initialization:

```
MyClass<2> a = MyClass<2>(vector<float>());
```

Or, since your constructor isn't `explicit`, you could use:

```
MyClass<2> a = vector<float>();
```

(Though, unless you mean for `vector<float>` objects to be implicitly convertible to `MyClass<N>` objects, you probably want to make this constructor `explicit`.)

---

A good compiler should warn you about this sort of thing.  Visual C++ warns:

> warning C4930: '`MyClass<x> a(std::vector<_Ty> (__cdecl *)(void))`': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)

Clang warns:

> warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declarator
>
> ```
> MyClass<2> a(vector<float>());
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Comment: why MyClass<2> a((vector<float>()))? Shouldn't this be the same as MyClass<2> a(vector<float>())?

Comment: @BlackBear:  With the extra parentheses, it isn't a valid function declaration, so it gets parsed as a variable declaration with a direct initializer.

Comment: Yes, it really seems that adding extra parentheses makes it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Clang error diagnostic is much powerful. +1 for posting Clang's error message. :)