# Passing a std::vector<char> constructed from istreambuf_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl

I have the following code:

```
std::ifstream ifs(fileName, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
std::vector<char> vecdata(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), 
                          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
image->setData(std::move(vecdata));
```

setData is declared as follows:

```
void Image::setData(std::vector<char> && data);
```

I have the following error:

> reader.cpp:752:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>
> 'Image::setData(std::vector
>   (&)(std::istreambuf_iterator >,
>   std::istreambuf_iterator > (*)()))'
>
> ```
> image->setData(std::move(vecdata));
>                                  ^
> ```
>
> candidate is:
>
> image.h:12: void Image::setData(std::vector&&)

I am using gcc 4.91

MCVE with gcc 5.4, same behavior : http://rextester.com/QYA50737

Is this a gcc bug?

Thanks

Comment: Most Vexing Parse is the key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363748/constructor-not-returning-usable-object

Comment: I got the idea by searching for most vexing parse. The second parameter can be interpreted as an unnamed pointer to a function returning a istreambuf_iterator<char>. But how can the first parameter be interpreted as a function declaration argument? To me it can only be a rvalue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got Most Vexing Parse: use `{}` instead of `()`:

```
std::vector<char> vecdata{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), 
                          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
```

Comment: isn't `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)` a value, i.e. not a type?

Comment: @PiotrNycz no, in OP's code it is a variable called `ifs` with the type `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`.

Comment: @mch Not a variable; a parameter.

Comment: How can `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)` be a parameter declaration??

Comment: @galinette: `int main(int (argc), char**(argv))` is valid. Whereas for extra parents here is not needed, it would be for case like `int (*a)[42]`

Comment: How is this not the case all the time? I have zillions of constructor calls which could be parsed as function declarations, but this has never been the case until today.