# Not able to pass data to priority_queue in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue

This is my comparator class which provides STL priority_queue logic for comparing elements.

```
class Comp {
 public:
  bool operator() (pair<int, int>& a, pair<int, int>& b) {
    int val1 = vec[a.first][a.second];
    int val2 = vec[b.first][b.second];
    return val1 > val2;
  }
};
```

as you can see for this comparison logic to work properly I need to provide a 2D vector to this class.

so, I modified the class as -

```
class Comp {
  vector<vector<int>> vec;

 public:
  Comp(vector<vector<int>>& v): vec{v} {} 

  bool operator() (pair<int, int>& a, pair<int, int>& b) {
    int val1 = vec[a.first][a.second];
    int val2 = vec[b.first][b.second];
    return val1 > val2;
  }
};
```

and I am getting that 2D array into a function, in which I need to initialize the priority_queue as well.

code for that function -

```
class random {
public:
    vector<int> func(vector<vector<int>> vec, int k) {
        priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, Comp> pq;
        //
    }
};
```

now the problem is I do not know how can I provide the required 2D array 'vec' to my comparison logic.

Does anyone know how to do that?

complete code -

```
class Comp {
    vector<vector<int>> vec;

public:
    Comp(vector<vector<int>>& v): vec{v} {} 

    bool operator() (pair<int, int>& a, pair<int, int>& b) {
        int val1 = vec[a.first][a.second];
        int val2 = vec[b.first][b.second];
        return val1 > val2;
    }
};

class random {
public:
    vector<int> func(vector<vector<int>> vec, int k) {
        priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, Comp> pq;
        //
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried `pq(Comp(vec))`?

Comment: @awesoon can you please elaborate on your comment by writing the complete command statement.

Comment: You need to pass `Comp` to the `pq` constructor. Just replace `pq` with `pq(Comp(vec))`

Comment: @awesoon you mean like this

 `priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, Comp> pq(Comp(vec));` ?


it is giving me error `expression must have class type`

Answer (score 1):

As awesoon pointed out, you have to pass an instantiation of you Comp class to the constructor of std::priority_queue.
But you have to use braces instead of parantheses to avoid ambiguity with a function declaration (cmp. [Constructor not returning usable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363748/constructor-not-returning-usable-object)).

Your example with added constructor call: https://godbolt.org/z/18b4KT66v